# Loop through the sheets and calculate the sum using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel , I have to add the time allocated to different departments per month and also annually.So the excel has sheets 12 sheets that are from January to December. It looks like this : (Jan)
[image: January Sheet]

The same is repeated for other months of the year.But the time allocated may be different and some departments may not be mentioned at all.

The task is I have to do is to add all the time effort allocated to different departments in different months and show it on a sheet.
Something along the line :

[image: Time Effort for different months]

And at last in another sheet, I have to add all the time effort for different departments for the whole year.
Something along the line:

[image: Time effort for the whole year]

I was wondering is there a way I could achieve this using VBA scripting.Kindly help.

Comment: Have you considered pivot tables as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two additional sheets. One called `Monthly` and the other called `Yearly`. Assumes data starts in `A2` in each sheet (ignoring headers).

**Code to go in standard module:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTimeAllocations()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim monthsArr()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    monthsArr = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

    Dim monthDict As Object
    Dim wsMonthly As Worksheet
    Dim wsYearly As Worksheet

    Set monthDict = GetMonthDictionary(wb, monthsArr)
    Set wsMonthly = wb.Worksheets("Monthly")
    Set wsYearly = wb.Worksheets("Yearly")

    wsMonthly.UsedRange.ClearContents 'to clear out anything in sheet before writing to it
    wsYearly.UsedRange.ClearContents

    WriteOutData wsMonthly, wsYearly, monthDict

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ws

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    GetLastRow = lastRow

End Function
Public Function GetMonthDictionary(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal monthsArr As Variant) As Object

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentMonth As Long
    Dim monthDict As Object

    Set monthDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For currentMonth = LBound(monthsArr, 1) To UBound(monthsArr, 1)

        On Error Resume Next

        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(monthsArr(currentMonth))
        lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1)

        Dim valuesArr()
        valuesArr = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value2

        Dim currentItem As Long

        For currentItem = LBound(valuesArr, 1) To UBound(valuesArr, 1)

            Dim monthDept As String
            Dim dept As String
            Dim hours As Double

            dept = Trim$(valuesArr(currentItem, 1))
            monthDept = ws.Name & "," & dept
            hours = CDbl(Split(Trim$(valuesArr(currentItem, 2)), " ")(0))

            If Not monthDict.Exists(monthDept) Then
                monthDict.Add monthDept, hours
                monthDict.Add dept, hours
            Else
                monthDict(monthDept) = monthDict(monthDept) + hours
                monthDict(dept) = monthDict(dept) + hours

            End If

        Next currentItem

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set ws = Nothing

    Next currentMonth

    Set GetMonthDictionary = monthDict

End Function

Public Sub WriteOutData(ByVal wsMonthly As Worksheet, ByVal wsYearly As Worksheet, ByVal monthDict As Object)

    Dim outputRow As Long
    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In monthDict.Keys

        If InStr(1, key, ",") > 0 Then           'Month,Dept  Hours

            outputRow = outputRow + 1

            With wsMonthly

                .Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Split(key, ",")
                .Cells(outputRow, 3) = monthDict(key) & " hrs"

            End With

        Else                                     'Yearly figure Dept, Hours (total)

            With wsYearly

                .Cells(outputRow, 1) = key
                .Cells(outputRow, 2) = monthDict(key) & " hrs"

            End With

        End If

    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It is working but I am facing one problem.In the Monthly sheet month name is printing for all the rows , but i dont want that to happen

Comment: That would take a little more fiddling. Are you able to wait a day or two more for when I have proper time to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to set up your Excel workbook differently than you have.  One sensible way is as shown in the animated gif below. I've only done the first 3 months to demonstrate, and I have the formulas displayed in each cell at the first part, and then switch to showing the result at the end. If you set it up this way, all the results you want will appear automatically without the need for any vba. Let me know if you have questions.

[image]